# How to run httpFilters in playframework 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4, macwire

I am trying to build application on Playframework 2.4 with macwire DI, and I have problem with httpFilters from Play ! Here is an example what I'm trying to do

```
class ExampleFilter extends Filter {
  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
      result.withHeaders("Example" -> "test")
    }
  }
}

class Filters(ex:ExampleFilter) extends HttpFilters {
  val filters = Seq(ex)
}
```

DI module

```
trait Module extends EhCacheComponents with BuiltInComponents {

  lazy val exampleFilter = wire[ExampleFilter]
  lazy val filters = wire[Filters]
```

Loader class

```
class Loader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    new MyComponents(context).application
  }
}

class MyComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with Module {
  lazy val router: Router = wire[Routes] withPrefix "/"
}
```

part of application.conf is

```
play.http.filters = Filters
```

and ExampleFilter doesn't work. I'm getting response without "Example" header

Comment: Have you configured your application loader in the application.conf? play.application.loader=Loader

Comment: Yes everything works fine besides those filters

Answer (score 1):

it looks like that I have found the solution

```
class MyComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with Module {
  override lazy val httpFilters = Seq(ExampleFilter)
  lazy val router: Router = wire[Routes] withPrefix "/"
}
```

, just override **httpFilters** from **BuiltInComponents** trait (like above), and change **ExampleFilter** to object and it works

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Filters` is in the unnamed (default) package. Put it somewhere in the package, like `appfilters.Filters`.

So

```
package appfilters

...

class Filters(ex:ExampleFilter) extends HttpFilters {

...
```

and

```
play.http.filters = appfilters.Filters
```